# Auslander-Reiten Quiver through Polygons

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I'm familiar with drawing quivers/AR-quivers in tikzcd, however in Ralf Schiffler's 2014 text he utilizes regular polygons to construct the AR-quiver of type An or Dn. I was wondering if anyone has any decent insight in replicating these types of diagrams. Apologies for only having two screenshots. The first image is of type An:
[image: AR quiver found on page 77 of Schiffler]

The next one is for a quiver of type Dn:
[image: AR quiver found on page 93 of Schiffler]

Edit: To clarify what I'm looking for, it would be nice to get the first diagram in its entirety. If someone recognizes how to do the second diagram, that would be great as well. I've attached my current attempt of the first document below.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{cd}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\def\oct{\draw(A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- (F) -- (G) -- (H) --cycle;}
\newcommand{\slice}[1]{\oct \draw \foreach \x/\y in {#1} {(\x)--(\y)};}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
  % define base octagon
  \coordinate (A) at (1, 2.414213562);
  \coordinate (B) at (-1, 2.414213562);
  \coordinate (C) at (-2.414213562, 1);
  \coordinate (D) at (-2.414213562, -1);
  \coordinate (E) at (-1, -2.414213562);
  \coordinate (F) at (1, -2.414213562);
  \coordinate (G) at (2.414213562, -1);
  \coordinate (H) at (2.414213562, 1);
  
  % present octagons with respective diagonals, in the Auslander-Reiten quiver
  \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=small, column sep=small, ampersand replacement=\&]
    \&\& \slice{A/G} \&\& \slice{B/H} \&\& \\
    \& \slice{A/F} \&\& \slice{B/G} \&\& \slice{C/H} \& \\
    \&\& \slice{B/F} \&\& \slice{C/G} \&\& \slice{D/H} \\
    \& \slice{B/E} \&\& \slice{C/F} \&\& \slice{D/G} \& \\
    \slice{B/D} \&\& \slice{C/E} \&\& \slice{D/F} \&\& \slice{E/G}
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{tikzpicture}\]

\end{document}
```

I should mention that in the drawing of the AR-quiver as I have above, I have not drawn the arrows between the octagon nodes yet.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think it whould be nice if you could explain a bit what you want to achieve in the end. Do you only want to create these two diagrams? In this case, you should probably come up with some starting code of your own, so that we know what you did so far and where you got stuck. If you aim for a rather general approach, however, that allows to create diagrams with different shapes and edges, you should probably explain a bit how the system works and which parts of the diagrams you want to be customisable.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Edited, hopefully that clarifies things a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

This is a solution for your first picture. It creates a `\pic` that draws an octagon and put some coordinates in it (vertices and cardinal points). Then in the `tikzpicture` it repeats with `\foreach` loops the octagons and the arrows that connects them. I also use a scale and a rotation for easier numbers.

Like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset
{% OCTAGON
  pics/octa/.style n args={3}{% #1 name, #2 fist point, #3 second point
    code={%
      \def\l{0.5}
      \draw  (22.5:\l) coordinate (1) --  (67.5:\l) coordinate (2) -- (112.5:\l) coordinate (3) --
            (157.5:\l) coordinate (4) -- (202.5:\l) coordinate (5) -- (247.5:\l) coordinate (6) --
            (292.5:\l) coordinate (7) -- (337.5:\l) coordinate (8) -- cycle;
      \draw (#2) -- (#3);
      \coordinate (#1-NW) at  (45:1.5*\l);
      \coordinate (#1-NE) at (135:1.5*\l);
      \coordinate (#1-SE) at (225:1.5*\l);
      \coordinate (#1-SW) at (315:1.5*\l);
    }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=45,scale=2.5]
\foreach\i in {4}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{mod(\i+3,8)+1}
  \pic at (\i,1) {octa={1\i}{6}{\j}};
  
\foreach\i in {3,4,5}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{mod(\i+3,8)+1}
  \pic at (\i,2) {octa={2\i}{5}{\j}};
 
\foreach\i in {2,...,5}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{mod(\i+3,8)+1}
  \pic at (\i,3) {octa={3\i}{4}{\j}};

\foreach\i in {1,...,5}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{mod(\i+3,8)+1}
  \pic at (\i,4) {octa={4\i}{3}{\j}};

\foreach\i in {3,4}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{mod(\i+3,8)+1}
  \pic at (\i,5) {octa={5\i}{2}{\j}};

\foreach\i in {23,24,32,33,34,41,42,43,44,53}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i+1}
  \draw[-latex] (\i-NW) -- (\j-SE);

\foreach\i in {24,33,34,35,42,43,44,45,53,54}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i-10}
  \draw[-latex] (\i-SW) -- (\j-NE);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Certainly appreciate it.